# How to change the jquery table footer for pagin

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Hello friends I have jquery grid with paging at the footer of the grid,

i have >> > arrows for next and last.. 
istead of that can i define First Previous , Next and Last

here is the Code which I have for Find, Columns and refresh the Grid..

thanks

Comment: can you give the name of the plugin you're using?

Comment: I belive it is jqgird. jqgrid.com

Comment: @rockers  your response to nathan's question and my assumption makes no sense.  jquery-1.4.2.min.js is the Jquery framework.  are you using jqgrid or not.  look at http://jqgrid.com and tell me if that is the grid you are using

Comment: I am using newer version of Jquery
http://www.trirand.net/demoaspnetmvc.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me the code like following will solve your requirement:

```
jQuery("span.ui-icon-seek-first").removeClass("ui-icon").text("First");
jQuery("span.ui-icon-seek-prev").removeClass("ui-icon").text("Prev");
jQuery("span.ui-icon-seek-next").removeClass("ui-icon").text("Next");
jQuery("span.ui-icon-seek-end").removeClass("ui-icon").text("Last");
```

you can use `jQuery("#gbox_" + id)` as a context of jQuery (second parameter of jQuery), where id is the id of the jqGrid (like "list") if you want modify paging buttons only for one selected jqGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Rockers,
   I believe the only way to change those buttons is to

1. Remove the pager controls and create your own tool bar controls
2. Restyle the ui-icon ui-icon-seek-next ui-icon-seek-end and all other associated classes for the pager to display a different image or some text.

Comment: Please can you check my update with the code which I have for Columns,refresh and Find..

Answer (score 0):

you can go to the .js file of plugin. And you will see that everything is defined there. Just change there what you want.Its as simple